# Google "auto answers" what are they called and is there an API?

Tags: python, api, search

When you query google for information, google itself usually offers an answer before you click on any site.

For example
"Who is the richest person in the world"

Google : "Bill gates". I am wondering A: what this service's name is. And B: if there is an API we can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everybody's help. Wolfram alpha was the solution I needed

Answer (score 0):

No there is no api available for this. Google simply refers this feature as the **Answer Box**. The closest thing I could think of is [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/api) api